# Issue with Form's RecordSource: "This recordset is not updatable"

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm having issues where I'm unable to update any fields in my form.
I'll get "This recordset is not updatable" when I try to modify some fields.

I had to working when I inner joined 2 tables on my Form's Record Source.

```
SELECT dbo_Menzits.*, dbo_CCC_Job.*

FROM dbo_Menzits 

INNER JOIN dbo_CCC_Job ON dbo_Menzits.MenzitID = dbo_CCC_Job.ExternalId
```

However when i try to join another table it won't allow me to update the recordset (as shown below). I know Access has some rules that needs to be followed as specified [Here](http://rogersaccessblog.blogspot.com/2009/11/this-recordset-is-not-updateable-why.html) but I'm unable to understand some of the rules.

All my tables are linked tables and they all have primary keys.

[image: Record Source]

This is how i joined it:

```
SELECT dbo_Menzits.*, dbo_CCC_Job.*, dbo_jms_JobDetails.*

FROM (dbo_Menzits 

INNER JOIN dbo_jms_JobDetails ON dbo_Menzits.MenzitID = dbo_jms_JobDetails.MenzitID) 

INNER JOIN dbo_CCC_Job ON dbo_Menzits.MenzitID = dbo_CCC_Job.ExternalId
```

Comment: Consider #5 and #10 in the list on the linked article.  Although the tables have primary keys specified, just looking at the relationship in the image indicates a possible many-to-one-to-many relationship since there could be multiple matching records in both JobDetails and Job table.  In such a relationship, if you updated a column in one row, it would have to automatically update the same field in other rows linked through the same key values, but Access does not track and update such cascading relationships.

Comment: Depending on what your ultimate goal is, consider creating a form with sub-forms with proper `LinkMasterFields` and `LinkChildFileds` properties.  This would allow you to edit the main form and the records in each sub-form.

Comment: @CPerkins The relationship between the 3 tables should be 1 to 1 to 1 for example: There is only 1 JobID in the jms_JobDetailsTable which links to 1 MenzitID in the Menzit table and it also links to 1 Id in the CCC_Job tables. You do have a point about Access not being able to update multiple tables if I updated one column in one row however if none of the tables share the same column name would that be okay?

Comment: @CPerkins Another question is if I inner join a view with my Menzit table then it's definitely not going to be editable because Access can't edit views?

Comment: If Menzits truly has 1-to-1 relationship with the other 2 tables (Menzits is master and the others are dependent), it is possible to edit existing records in a query with all 3 tables - I do this. But creating new records is not. I use VBA to create records in the various tables then at a later time users open a form to add more data. Try LEFT JOIN. I agree, form/subform arrangement is the easiest approach.

Comment: @June7 I tried using subforms and it worked however I want the controls (Textfields etc) to show up on the main form. Is that possible with Access?

Comment: The only way for Access to "know" of a one-to-one relationship is to add a unique index on the foreign key, otherwise it must assume that there are multiple possible matches.  (By the way, this has nothing to do with column name matching.  Some databases use name-matching to auto-generate relationships, but making them distinct names won't help at all.)  I know that a primary key can be specified for linked tables, but honestly I'm not sure if another index can be added to a linked table, nor if Access will honor this relationship to make an updateable query.  Try it.

Comment: As @CPerkins said, the child tables link fields have to at least be indexed as unique, if not set as primary key. I have to recant my statement about not being able to add new records. That does work. However, if you cannot modify the linked tables to set index, cannot have all controls on one form and therefore must use form/subform.

Comment: @CPerkins  To add a unique index on the foreign key since I'm using a linked table, I'll need to modify it in SQL and use ODBC database? What about if my 3rd table jms_JobDetail is only being used to display information on controls and doesn't need any of the fields to be update-able. Can I somehow modify the Record source with VBA to do that and have all the controls on one form?

Comment: Now you're going beyond the scope of this question.  I do know that you would need a unique index as I said earlier, but right now I'm not able to test and outline details of how (or if) it can be done in your setup.  You can use VBA code to do all sorts of things (anything?) beyond the standard functionality of the form.  That's the entire purpose of VBA within Access... so the answer is of course **"yes"**. You could generate a new query and update form details in the Form_Current() event handler, for example.